# Did the exile of the Platonic academy facilitate the foundation of the House of Wisdom?

Tags: byzantine-empire, persia, neoplatonic-academy

According to Wikipedia:

> ...The last Scholarch of the Academy was Damascius (d. 540). According to Agathias, its remaining members looked for protection under the rule of Sassanid king Khosrau I in his capital at Ctesiphon, carrying with them precious scrolls of literature and philosophy, and to a lesser degree of science. After a peace treaty between the Persian and the Byzantine empire in 532, their personal security (an early document in the history of freedom of religion) was guaranteed.
>
> It has been speculated that the Academy did not altogether disappear.[34][36] After his exile, Simplicius (and perhaps some others), may have traveled to Harran, near Edessa. From there, the students of an Academy-in-exile could have survived into the 9th century, long enough to facilitate an Arabic revival of the Neoplatonist commentary tradition in Baghdad,

[Wikipedia - Platonic Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_Academy)

From what I understand, the forming of the House of Wisdom was facilitated by the carrying over of knowledge by scholars from multiple sources such as Constantinople, Alexandria, Gondishapur etc...

Is there any firm, concrete evidence that the neoplatonic academy facilitated the foundations or the forming of the House of Wisdom as stated in the article?

Comment: Did the discovery of the New World by Columbus facilitate the American Revolutionary War? Or did the end of the Thirty Years War facilitate the start of the World War II? Well, yeah. But other stuff that happened in those 300 years in between was probably important